# Make two different POST request from a form express/js/mongo

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, post

```
   <html>
    <body>
        <form method='POST'>
           <p>This is data from the databse</p>
           <input type='text' placeholder='Update the current text'>
           <button id="up">Update this</button>
           <button id="del">Delete this</button>
       </form>                       
     </body>
  </html>
```

I just want to add update and delete button in the form and send request to the express accourding. But how can I do so?

Here data loads from the mongo db. Then how to send different post requests from same form???

Also, I don't wanna use AJAX request.
I have read some other solutions but none of them was helpful or I understood.
So, please help me in a lucid way.

Comment: [The HTML5 placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Answer (score 0):

Give the submit buttons a name and different values.

```
<button name="action" value="update" id="up">Update this</button>
<button name="action" value="delete" id="del">Delete this</button>
```

Only the clicked submit button will be successful (i.e. appear in the submitted data).

On the server, check the value of `req.body.action` and act accordingly.

Comment: app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body.action);
    });

Comment: app.post('/', (req, res) => {
        console.log(req.body.action);
    });